# Why doesn't this disable directory listing for my site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using `Options –Indexes` in a `.htaccess` file in the directory I want to disable listing, but still when I go to the directory I can see all the files in that directory. What am I doing wrong? (Apache server).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have `DirectorySlash` turned off? It makes it so requests for directories that are missing the trailing slash gets redirected to the same directory *with* the trailing slash. By default it is on, but if it's turned off, it has a [strange side effect that allows listing of directories regardless of the `Indexes` options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is active (Options +Indexes) and DirectoryIndex is set to a valid resource (say, index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the index.html file. But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.